# PowerMock + EasyMock unexpected method call

Tags: unit-testing, junit4, easymock, powermock

I have a method like this which I want to unit test

```
public void update(String collectionName, BasicDBObject query, BasicDBObject updateObj){
    try{
        DBCollection collection = getCollection(collectionName);
        collection.update(query, updateObj, true, false);

    } catch (MongoException e) {
        if (e.getMessage().startsWith("can't call something")) {
               refreshConnection(collectionName);
            } else {
                throw e;
            }
    }
}
```

And the test code is as below. I have tried both the methods in the comments in unit test case and currently have commented it.

```
@Test
public void testUpdate(){
    MongoStore store = PowerMock.createStrictPartialMockForAllMethodsExcept(MongoStore.class, "update");
    DBCollection collection = PowerMock.createMock(DBCollection.class);

    BasicDBObject updateobj = new BasicDBObject("test","shrikar");
    String name = "testcoll";
    String id = "123";
    BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("id",id);
    EasyMock.expect(store.getCollection(name)).andReturn(collection);
    //EasyMock.expect(collection.update(EasyMock.anyObject(BasicDBObject.class),EasyMock.anyObject(BasicDBObject.class),EasyMock.anyBoolean(),EasyMock.anyBoolean()));
    //EasyMock.expect(collection.update(query,updateobj,true,false));
    PowerMock.replayAll();
    store.update(name,query,updateobj);
    EasyMock.expectLastCall().times(1);

    PowerMock.verifyAll();
}
```

In all the cases I keep getting

```
Unexpected Method call DBCollection.update({"id":"123"},{"test":"shrikar"}, true, false)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found out the problem I had forgotten to add Mongo*.class to PrepareForTest

```
@PrepareForTest({MongoStore.class,MongoOptions.class,Mongo.class, BasicDBObject.class,DBCursor.class,DBObject.class})
```